# How H2O AutoMachineLearning decide the model order?

Tags: python, classification, h2o, automl

I have to solve a simple binary classification problem using **H2O AutoML**. I'd like to know if the parameters  `sort_metric` and `stopping_metric` can somehow influence the order of the trained model.

I try to change these two parameters using both `AUC` or `AUCPR`, but the performances are almost identical.

My principal objective is to obtain the best algorithms in terms of `AUCPR`, so I would like to somehow influence the order of the trained models.

Does someone know how can I do so?

Comment: By "order" do you mean to want to change the relative ranking of models in the leaderboard? If so `sort_metric` is exactly what you want: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/sort_metric.html   But that won't change the accuracy/predictions of the individual models at all.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I understand that ```sort_metric``` is the right parameter in order to change leaderboard order, but it doesn't affect directly the training. Anyway, I think it would be more effective a change directly into the loss function. Is it possible to specify such a parameter in AutoML?